Why doesn't my java program work on VS Code?

I want to run the main class, but I get this on my terminal:
Main.java:3: error: package data does not exist
import data.Admin;
           ^
Main.java:4: error: package data does not exist
import data.Student;
           ^
Main.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    Admin admin = Admin.getInstance();
    ^
  symbol:   class Admin
  location: class Main
Main.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    Admin admin = Admin.getInstance();
                  ^
  symbol:   variable Admin
  location: class Main
Main.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        Student foundStudent = null;
        ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class Main
Main.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
        for (Student student : admin.studentList) {
             ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class Main
6 errors

When I run that program from IntelliJ, it works, but when I run it from VS Code, I get that error message.

How do you "run" your program? What plugins have you installed in VSCode? And please [edit] your question to include the full and complete build output, which should also show the command used to build.

Have you actually compiled that code? Where did you get 'TUGAS1' from?

https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/

The error shows that Java cannot find Admin and Student classes. Please check your classpath by the following steps:

Open the Command Palette by shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P".

Search for "Java: Configure Classpath".

In the file explorer, navigate to the directory that contains your data package and select it.


